# Pandas Import not Inserting All Rows

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am importing a .csv file with 3300 rows of data via the following:

```
myCSVfile = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
myCSVfile.to_sql(con=engine, name='foo', if_exists='replace')
```

Once successfully imported, I do a "select * from ..." query on my table, which returns 3100 rows, so where are the missing 200 rows?

I am assuming there is corrupt data which cannot be read in, which I further assume is then skipped over by pandas. However there is no warning, log or message to explicitly say so. The script executes as normal.

Has anyone experienced similar problems, or am I missing something completely obvious?

Comment: A bit unclear where you think it fails. Have you checked how many rows are read in from the file? e.g. `myCSVfile.shape`

Comment: Could it be that the csv file contains duplicate keys? You did use if_exists='replace'.

Comment: Apologies if description was quite vague. In short, yes I have ran multiple prints at every stage of the process to track it all and the numbers only differ after the import which is why I assume the issue lies within the .to_sql function. @JohnSloper

Comment: @Spinor8 I have checked for duplicates also yes, there were < 10 which I found. However, there are still plenty missing rows.

Comment: if_exists applies to the database entity and how to treat it. It can be 'appended' to among other behaviors.  But should not be culpable for the loss of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question does not specify `engine`, let's assume it is `sqlite3`.

The follow re-runnable code shows that DataFrame.to_sql() creates a `sqlite3` table, and places an index on it.  Which is the data from the index of the dataframe.

Taking the question code literally, the csv should import into the DataFrame with a `RangeIndex` which will be unique ordinals.  Because of this, one should be surprised if the number of rows in the csv do not match the number of rows loaded into the `sqlite3` table.

So there are two things to do:  Verify that the csv is being imported correctly.  This is likely the problem since poorly formatted csv files, originating from human  manipulated spreadsheets, frequently fail when manipulated by code for a variety of reasons. But that is impossible to answer here because we do not know the input data.

However, what `DataFrame.to_sql()` does should be excluded.  And for that, `method` can be passed in.  It can be used to see what `DataFrame.to_sql()` does with the DataFrame data prior to handing it off to the SQL `engine`.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

def dump_foo(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM foo")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)

conn = sqlite3.connect('example145.db')

csv_data = """1,01-01-2019,724
2,01-01-2019,233,436
3,01-01-2019,345
4,01-01-2019,803,933,943,923,954
4,01-01-2019,803,933,943,923,954
4,01-01-2019,803,933,943,923,954
4,01-01-2019,803,933,943,923,954
4,01-01-2019,803,933,943,923,954
5,01-01-2019,454
5,01-01-2019,454
5,01-01-2019,454
5,01-01-2019,454
5,01-01-2019,454"""

with open('test145.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(csv_data)

with open('test145.csv') as csvfile:
    data = [row for row in csv.reader(csvfile)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)

def checkit(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    print "What pandas wants to put into sqlite3"
    for row in data_iter:
        print(row)

# note, if_exists replaces the table and does not affect the data
df.to_sql('foo', conn, if_exists="replace", method=checkit)
df.to_sql('foo', conn, if_exists="replace")
print "*** What went into sqlite3"
dump_foo(conn)
```